# How to partition or subset a nested dataframe with a list of index in R?

Tags: r, nested, subset, partitioning

I am trying to creating a training dataframe for fitting my model. The dataframe I am working with is a nested dataframe. Using `createDataPartition` , I have created a list of indexes. But I am having trouble subsetting the dataframe with said list.

Here is what the object `partitionindex` created by `caret::createDataParition` looks like:

```
 partitionindex
[[1]]
[[1]]$Resample1
  [1]   4   5   6   8   9  10  11  12  14  15  17  18  20  21  23  28  30  32  34  38  39  41  42  46
 [25]  47  48  50  52  53  56  57  58  59  60  64  66  67  70  73  75  76  77  78  82  85  87  90  95
 [49]  97  99 105 106 110 113 114 116 117 118 119 120 123 124 126 128 129 130 132 134 135 137 139 141
 [73] 142 143 144 145 146 148 149 151 153 154 155 157 158 164 165 167 170 174 176 178 182 183 184 186
 [97] 189 190 191 193 194 197 198 200 201 202 203 206 210 211 212 213 214 216 219 221 222 223 226 232
[121] 236 237 241 243 247 248 251 254 255 256 258 262 263 264 269 270 271 274 276 277 280 281 284 291
[145] 292 293 295 296 297 299 300 301 302 303 304 309 314 317 318 319 320 323 324 327 328 329 339 341
[169] 342 343 344 345 349 350 351 353 354 355 356 360 361 363 364 365 367 370 371 375 379 380


[[2]]
[[2]]$Resample1
  [1]   1   2   4   5   7   8   9  10  14  17  19  22  24  26  28  29  31  32  34  36  37  42  44  45
 [25]  47  48  49  51  52  53  56  58  65  66  67  68  72  74  75  77  78  81  83  86  95  96  98 100
 [49] 102 104 105 106 110 113 114 115 118 119 122 123 124 125 128 129 130 132 135 137 142 144 145 147
 [73] 149 150 151 152 158 160 161 163 165 168 169 170 171 175 176 180 183 186 187 188 191 194 196 199
 [97] 203 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 213 215 218 220 221 222 224 225 227 228 231 233 240 241 242 243
[121] 247 248 250 251 254 255 256 257 258 262 263 264 267 268 269 270 272 273 277 278 282 285 286 288
[145] 289 290 292 293 294 295 296 300 301 302 304 305 307 308 312 314 315 316 317 321 323 328 329 332
[169] 333 335 336 339 341 343 344 345 347 348 349 354 355 359 360 362 363 366 369 374 375 376 377


[[3]]
[[3]]$Resample1
  [1]   5   8  10  12  17  22  25  26  27  30  32  33  34  36  38  39  42  44  45  46  47  51  52  57
 [25]  58  59  62  64  66  70  71  73  75  78  81  82  83  84  86  89  90  95  96  97  98 100 103 104
 [49] 105 108 109 111 112 113 114 117 119 120 121 123 124 127 130 131 132 133 137 139 140 141 144 148
 [73] 149 150 151 153 154 155 156 157 159 160 163 164 167 168 170 172 173 176 178 179 181 182 184 186
 [97] 187 188 189 190 191 207 208 212 214 215 219 220 222 223 227 230 233 234 238 248 250 251 252 253
[121] 256 258 260 261 262 264 265 266 267 270 271 272 275 278 281 285 288 289 291 293 295 297 298 302
[145] 303 305 306 308 312 314 315 318 319 320 321 323 325 326 329 332 333 334 335 336 338 342 343 345
[169] 347 348 349 350 351 352 360 361 363 364 365 366 368 369 370 371 372 374 375 376 377 378


[[4]]
[[4]]$Resample1
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  10  12  14  15  18  19  20  22  23  25  26  27  28  30  31  34
 [25]  37  38  40  44  45  46  47  49  50  51  52  59  62  64  66  68  70  71  72  73  75  76  79  80
 [49]  81  83  84  86  88  89  91  92  94  95  96  97  99 100 102 105 108 109 112 119 125 126 129 130
 [73] 132 134 137 139 140 141 145 150 153 155 156 158 159 162 163 170 178 179 181 182 184 185 187 188
 [97] 190 191 192 194 196 197 199 201 205 206 207 218 219 220 223 229 230 231 232 237 238 240 241 242
[121] 244 245 247 248 249 251 252 253 257 258 260 261 263 264 265 266 270 271 273 275 276 283 285 289
[145] 290 291 294 298 299 300 302 303 304 306 307
```

And the nested dataframe:

```
> nested_df
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   League [4]
  League                     data
  <chr>          <list<df[,133]>>
1 F1           [380 x 133]
2 E0           [380 x 133]
3 SP1          [380 x 133]
4 D1           [308 x 133]
```

I tried something like this but to no avail:

```
nested_df%>%
  mutate(train = data[map(data,~.x[partitionindex,])])
Error in x[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Is there a solution involving `purrr::map` or `lappy`?

Comment: Try removing the `data[` part and just call `map` on the data column

Comment: @camille It still gives the error `Error in x[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could work, with `purrr::pmap`

```
nested_df %>%
ungroup() %>%  # make sure the table is not grouped
mutate(i = row_number()) %>%
mutate(train = pmap(
    .,
    function(data, i, ...) {
        data[partitionindex[[i]]$Resample1,]
    }
)) %>%
select(-i)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but doesnt this only use the index in $Resample1? I needed F1 to be subsetted with Resample1, E0 to be subsetted with Resample2, SP1 to be subsetted with Resample3 etc. Thanks!

Comment: What is the structure of `partitionindex` exactly ? I thought it was complete here, since you have 4 dataframes to subset, and there are 4 elements in the list.

Comment: Btw, you can provide the data (or a representative subset of them at least) using `dput()`, so that it is easier to understand and test.

Comment: oops, just disregard my comment there, what I mean is subset F1 with `paritionindex[[1]]$Resample1`, E0 with `paritionindex[[2]]$Resample1`, SP1 with `paritionindex[[3]]$Resample1` etc. However, running your codes gives me the error: `Error: Column train must be length 1 (the group size), not 4`. Also, running just `mutate(i = row_number())` returned 1 for all four rows. Is this expected? Thanks

Comment: About `row_number()` : No. It means that your dataframe is grouped, so you should ungroup it before mutating. 
The other error also seems to be due to the same reason.
I have edited my answer by adding `ungroup()`, let me know if it still does not work.

Comment: one more question, how do I negative index on my test dataset? I have tired replacing the body section of your function with `data[-partitionindex[[i]]$Resample1`, but that gives me an error.